# How can I speed up my Haskell program (to the level of Python)

Tags: haskell

I have the following toy program which cyclic shifts a vector and adds it to itself (under a mod). It does that for different shifts and high number of iterations (compared to the size of the vector). Program works, but its dog slow. I am still learning Haskell, so my question is: am I doing something wrong?

```hs
import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Sequence (index, zipWith, Seq, (><), (<|), (|>))

seqSize = 100
numShifts = 10000 

cycleShift :: Integer -> Seq a -> Seq a
cycleShift s l = Seq.drop (fromInteger s) l >< Seq.take (fromInteger s) l

modAdd :: Seq Integer -> Seq Integer -> Seq Integer 
modAdd s t = Seq.zipWith (\ a b -> (a + b) `mod` 10^16) s t

step :: Seq Integer -> Integer -> Seq Integer
step l shift = modAdd l (cycleShift shift l)

allshifts = [i `mod` seqSize |i <- [1..numShifts]]
start = Seq.fromList (1 : [0 | i <- [1..(seqSize - 1)]])
end = foldl' step start allshifts

main :: IO ()
main = print (Seq.index end 0)
```

The same program in Python

```
seq_size = 100 
num_shifts = 10000

S = [i % seq_size for i in xrange(1, num_shifts + 1)]
ssums = [1] + [0 for i in range(seq_size - 1)]

for s in S: 
    shift = ssums[s:] + ssums[:s]  
    ssums = [(ssums[i] + shift[i]) % 10**16 for i in range(seq_size)]  

print ssums[0]
```

Here are the timings.
Haskell: real   0m5.596s
Python:  real   0m0.551s

Python is not known for it's speed and yet is x10 times faster ?!?

Comment: You might want to check out Real World Haskell's performance tuning section first. It helped me learn some of the basics. http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html

Answer (score 21):

How are you running it?

I get 1.6 seconds for the Haskell version. (Compiled with `ghc.exe -O2 seq.hs`.)

Also, is there a reason you're using Seq? If I change it to use lists, I get 0.3 seconds execution time.

Here it is with lists:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

seqSize = 100
numShifts = 10000 

cycleShift s l = drop (fromInteger s) l ++ take (fromInteger s) l

modAdd s t = zipWith (\ a b -> (a + b) `mod` 10^16) s t

step l shift = modAdd l (cycleShift shift l)

allshifts = [i `mod` seqSize |i <- [1..numShifts]]
start = (1 : [0 | i <- [1..(seqSize - 1)]])
end = foldl' step start allshifts

main :: IO ()
main = print (end !! 0)
```

Comment: Using rem instead of mod should also provide some speedup.

Comment: I tested it and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 20):

1. Use plain lists. They are heavily optimized. Using `Data.Vector` is even faster.
2. Use `rem` instead of `mod`
3. Avoid unnecessary work. (see `cycleShift`. Before, you splitted the list twice)
4. Use `Int` instead of `Integer` if your calculation may not exceed the bounds. The former is a hardware int, while the later is arbitrary precision, but emulated via software.

Result: 3.6 secs to 0.5 secs. More is probably possible.

Code:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Tuple

seqSize, numShifts :: Int
seqSize = 100

numShifts = 10000 

cycleShift :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
cycleShift s = uncurry (++) . swap . splitAt s

modAdd :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
modAdd = zipWith (\ a b -> (a + b) `rem` 10^16)

step :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
step l shift = modAdd l (cycleShift shift l)

allshifts = map (`rem` seqSize) [1..numShifts]
start = 1 : replicate (seqSize - 1) 0
end = foldl' step start allshifts

main :: IO ()
main = print (head end)
```

#### Edit

It gets even faster by using `Data.Vector`. I get around 0.4 sec on my machine using this code:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Tuple

import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector as V

seqSize, numShifts :: Int
seqSize = 100

numShifts = 10000 

cycleShift :: Int -> Vector a -> Vector a
cycleShift s = uncurry (V.++) . swap . V.splitAt s

modAdd :: Vector Int -> Vector Int -> Vector Int
modAdd = V.zipWith (\ a b -> (a + b) `rem` 10^16)

step :: Vector Int -> Int -> Vector Int
step l shift = modAdd l (cycleShift shift l)

allshifts = map (`rem` seqSize) [1..numShifts]
start = 1 `V.cons` V.replicate (seqSize - 1) 0
end = foldl' step start allshifts

main :: IO ()
main = print (V.head end)
```

#### Edit 2

Using `Data.Vector.Unboxed` (Just change the imports and fix up the signatures), the runtime drops down to 0.074 secs. But the results are only correct, if an `Int` has 64 bit. It may also be that fast using `Int64` though.

Comment: There's a slight problem here in that a Haskell Int is officially only guaranteed to cover the range  [ - 2^29, 2^29 - 1]. Note that 10^16 is greater than 2^29, so you could easily get Int wraparound happening in this code if that rem actually ever kicks in.

Comment: @chrisdb Sorry. GHC uses all 32 bits on x86 and 64 bits on x64 so I get no overflow. IMHO it changes not too much if you switch back to Integer.

Comment: I agree that an Int64 (or just Int on x64 if that's what GHC uses) is OK. An Int32 won't be in the general case (2^31 < 10^16, so wraparound happens before you hit the rem), so you'll just silently get the wrong answer. I'm not sure if it's an issue for numShifts = 10000 and seqSize = 100, so for this particular case you might get the right answer anyway.

Comment: Just a note: The first two changes make no difference for me. I get exactly the same results after as before.

Comment: And I get 0.15 for Vector version (twice as fast as lists) and 0.016 for Int32-unboxed version (but the wrong answer ;)).

Comment: @FUZxxl, do you have a typo, "runtime drops down to 0.74 secs"? from 0.4 secs?

Comment: @gatoatigrado I get 0.044 seconds for his last code snippet (using `-fllvm` too), so I'm guessing his measurement was `0.074`.

Comment: @Thomas Porges gatoatigrado Fixed the issue.

Comment: @FUZxxl, what heavy optimizations are you referring to w.r.t. to plain Lists? As compared to e.g. if I used my own `data Lst a = Cons a (Lst a) | Nil` definition?

Comment: @hvr Like list fusion. For instance, GHC is smart enough to change `map g . map f` into `map (g . f)`. There are some other optimizations, but I am not the guy who wrote GHC, so I am not sure.

Comment: @hvr: another problem is that overly-strict code can perform worse than lazy code (Sequence is a strict data structure). It's almost always better to write the 'easy' lazy version first and then strictify it where needed.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the Haskell code is compiled and the resulting executable is being timed, not the interpreted version of the code.

[TheGeekStuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/haskell-programming-hello-world/)